# Download folder.zip doesn't work in internet explorer, ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use this code to download file .zip, it works in chrome but it dosen't work in ie.

```
     Response.Clear();
     Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
     Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "Planning agent" + ".zip"));

     bool recurseDirectories = true;
     using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
     {
         zip.AddSelectedFiles("*", path, string.Empty, recurseDirectories);
         zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
     }

     Response.Flush();
     Response.End();
     Response.Clear();
```

Comment: Are you executing a REST api GET request? Just creating a Response manually doesn't make you download anything.

Comment: This is WebForms code, not MVC. In ASP.NET MVC and later use `return File(...)` to return a file

Comment: i use  public void DownloadFolder(string path)

Answer (score 1):

Is this a Controller code? If so, you might use Controller.File(Stream, String, String) overload and let asp.net code handle it for you. Perhaps something like that:

```
var mem = new MemoryStream();
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddSelectedFiles("*", path, string.Empty, true);
    zip.Save(mem);
}

mem.Position = 0;
return this.File(mem, "application/zip", "Planning agent.zip");
```

If it is not your case, I think this is related to headers formatting.

Comment: By formatting i mean how ie understand headers content. Ie not always behave as other browsers or follow a standardization.